# permissions 040 not readable by group?

Tags: file-permissions

I'm a bit confused by the permissions on a file.

Just to experiment, I tried the following as user "jorre"

```
chown jorre:jorre file.txt
chmod 040 file.txt
```

I would expect this file to be readable by user "jorre" since that user exists in the group "jorre". However, I'm getting permissions errors when trying to read the file.

Is that because I'm the owner of the file and group permissions are ignore because of that? I am in the group so I would have thought that group permissions would be valid in this case as well.

Thanks for clarifying this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you the user `jorre`, is the owner of the file.

The file permissions specifically do not allow read, write or execute of that file to the owner (`jorre`).

If you were to change the owner to another user, then you would be able to read the file under the group permissions.

*Excert from File system permissions [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions)*

> **Classes**
>   ...
>   The effective permissions are determined based on the user's class. For example, the user who is the owner of the file will have the permissions given to the owner class regardless of the permissions assigned to the group class or others class.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. So if you are the owner and belong to the group that owns the file, the owner permissions are the ones that count?

Comment: @solsol - Updated the answer to include `effective permissions` wiki extract.